# Creating white space in a List in Scala

Tags: scala, list, lambda, functional-programming

I am trying to convert a List of string to the form "rBrrBB", or "r r rb", or "   rrB". The string must have length 6. If the this list is not full, then the list should be prefixed with an appropriate number of spaces

So far my code as below

> def showColumn(xs: List[String]): String = xs match
>    {case List() => ""
>     case x::xs1 => x.format(" ") + showColumn(xs1)}

when I call this from

> println (showColumn(List("","","b","b","r","b")))

it returns only "bbrb". It suppose to return "  bbrb"
Any help would appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```scala
def showColumn(xs: List[String]): String = xs.map(x => if(x == "") " " else x).mkString
```

or, alternatively:

```scala
def showColumn(xs: List[String]): String = xs.map(x => if(x.isEmpty) " " else x).mkString
```

Both work by changing empty strings in the list to spaces, then merging each string in the list into a single string.

If you absolutely must make this a recursive function, then a solution which is not *tail-recursive* would look like this:

```scala
def showColumn(xs: List[String]): String = xs match {
  case Nil => ""
  case x :: xs1 => (if(x.isEmpty) " " else x) + showColumn(xs1)
}
```

Finally, the *tail-recursive* version is a little more complex, as it employs a helper function:

```scala
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def showColumn(xs: List[String]): String = {

  // Tail recursive helper function.
  @tailrec
  def nextStr(rem: List[String], acc: String): String = rem match {
    case Nil => acc
    case x :: xs1 => nextStr(xs1, acc + (if(x.isEmpty) " " else x))
  }

  // Start things off.
  nextStr(xs, "")
}
```